# Editing the DBF for a shapefile is yielding totally different results in R and QGIS, but the attribute tables are identical

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r, attribute-table, dbf

I'm having kind of a peculiar issue that I'm hoping someone can shed some light on. I'm actually creating my map in R, but I'm using QGIS as a tool to check my mapping process (R newb here). So let's dig into it.

I'm trying to plot rivers in my area of interest (Tanzania), but the source shapefile (diva-gis.org) includes tons of unnecessary water lines. For the sake of reproducability, I'll be including all edited DBFs and shapefiles. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8q448kehhbrirjm/original-waterlines.dbf?dl=0) is the original DBF file and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy90v3vgxt6csud/original-waterlines.shp?dl=0) is the original shapefile. It looks like this. [image]

As you can see in the DBF, many of the rivers are unknown/unnamed and listed as "UNK" which isn't very useful for me. In QGIS, I am simply able to open the attribute table, sort by name, and remove all UNK values. Alternatively, I can filter out those values through the SQL expression:

```
"NAM" != "UNK"
```

Both of these yield the same results. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5eu1a2y87kvhs7/qgis-edit.dbf?dl=0) is the QGIS edited DBF and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/925bkw0r5ona07r/qgis-edit.shp?dl=0) is the QGIS edited shapefile. This is what the map looks like: [image]

Then things get quirky. Again, I'm actually creating this map in R. Using the original source data, I edit the DBF with the "foreign" package, overwrite the DBF, and then map using ggplot. I'm getting a totally different result than the one pictured above. Here's a little snippet of example code (not for the full map, but this is essentially what this portion of the map code will look like):

```
library(rgdal)
library(foreign)
library(ggplot2)

#set your appropriate working directory
setwd("D:/Mapping-R/Returns-Practice")

#read dbf, sql expression to remove all UNK values in NAM
water.lines <- read.dbf("original-waterlines.dbf")
water.lines <- water.lines[water.lines$NAM != "UNK",]

#overwrite dbf
write.dbf(water.lines, "TZA_water_lines_dcw.dbf")

#read shapefile, fortify to create readable data frame
water.lines.shp <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Returns-Practice", 
                  layer = "original-waterlines")
water.lines.shp <- fortify(water.lines.shp)

#plot
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = water.lines.shp, 
             aes(long, lat, group = group), 
             color = "slategray4")
```

The result of this code looks like this: 
[image]

Kind of stretched out and funky, but clearly does not follow the same line pattern as the QGIS-edited image. This has been driving me absolutely nuts. I actually went through and checked the R attributes against the QGIS attributes and they matched up perfectly, but the image result is completely different. After playing around with it some more, I figured that my code was to blame and that's where I messed up. But then I opened the original DBF and manually removed all UNK values and plugged it back into QGIS. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3ahp6nfya54rxa/manual-edit.dbf?dl=0) is the resulting DBF and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bw63k6yn8smavb/manual-edit.shp?dl=0) is its corresponding shapefile, which matches the R image/plot and looks like this: 
[image]

What gives?! The attribute tables are identical but the images are different. I feel like there has to be something really obvious that I'm missing but I've been playing with this for literally hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: Looks like different projections used for views, geographic and projected in qgis

Comment: 1. You don't need the foreign package. Just use `water.lines.shp <- subset(water.lines.sho, NAM != "UNK")` after `readOGR()`. 2. add `coord_map()` to your plot.

Comment: You should have received an error if the .shp feature count was not equal to the .dbf record count.  I'd consider that a bug in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it in R.

```
library(rgdal)
# read in the shapefile
tz.wl <- readOGR(".", "TZA_water_lines_dcw")

# now select 
tz.wl.selection <- tz.wl[tz.wl$NAM != 'UNK',]

# you can write this out and compare with your Qgis file:
writeOGR(tz.wl.selection, ".", "TZA_water_lines_selection", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: Thank you, this appeared to work! This is actually where I started out, but I couldn't get past the @data issue. I originally had gotten to the selection point, but instead of using "tz.wl.selection <- tz.wl[tz.wl$NAM != "UNK",]",  I used"tz.wl.selection<- tz.wl$NAM[...]". This fixed that issue, and now I have the new shapefile. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Don't mess with Shapefile DBFs!

The connection between geometries and attributes gets messed up easily, especially if you start removing or reordering entries in the DBF. This will never work.

Use a different file format or use a library that supports Shapefiles as a whole and not just DBF.

Comment: I googled to hell and back how to remove the UNK values for the NAM column but that's the only solution I found! any other suggestions, or should I ask another question for that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do R. Better open a new question.